# Count dinstinct(), but only unique entries

Tags: sqlite, count

my table looks like this:

```
md5                                 other columns

098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
ad0234829205b9033196ba818f7a872b
ad0234829205b9033196ba818f7a872b
```

The md5 field is not unique.

But I want to count only the records that have unique md5. Can I do that in sqlite?

In my example above the count would be 1 (the first record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them by the hash:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) from someTable GROUP BY md5 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS sq;`

Comment: Whoops, sorry. You also have to count the returned ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT md5
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY md5
  HAVING COUNT(*)=1
) AS baseview
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(1) FROM (select distinct md5 from tablename) t
```